# Can't find my app on Google play on PC

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I published my app 3 days ago on Google play. I am able to find my app while browsing on phone, but when I try to find it on PC I can't find it.
I need it so I can link my app with my admob, question: Is this normal? How long it will take for app to appear on Google play for PC?
Is Linking App on Google play with admob important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the package name of your application? Go to this url appended with your package name:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.package
```

for example

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blundell

Comment: o yea I found it now. Wondering why it's not shown in Search tho...Anyway Thanks

Comment: It will need time to propagate all Google services for search to work, maybe in a few days